# Javascript: Trying to make a function to score matches between existing and selected indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I start with two data sets. One is a list of entry-tag pairs, called tags_entries. The other is a list of user-selected tags. For example,

```
tags_entries = [
         {'entry_id': 4, 'tag_id': 1},
         {'entry_id': 4, 'tag_id': 2},
         {'entry_id': 4, 'tag_id': 3},
         {'entry_id': 5, 'tag_id': 1},
         {'entry_id': 5, 'tag_id': 3}
]

usr_tags = [1,2];
```

I want my function, `score(tags_entries, usr_tags, target)`, to count the number of matching tags for each entry and return an object. So, for the example above, the result would be as follows:

```
result = {
         {'entry_id': 4, 'score': 2},
         {'entry_id': 5, 'score': 1}
}
```

This is the function I'm currently working on, and I'm having numerous problems:

```
function score_relevance2(tags_entries, usr_tags, target) {
    var result = {};
    var test = [];
    var i = tags_entries.length;

    while (i--) {

        result[tags_entries[i][target]] = {};
        result[tags_entries[i][target]]['tags'] = [];
        result[tags_entries[i][target]]['tags'].push(tags_entries[i]['tag_id']);

        // If member is a duplicate, delete it      
        if (result.hasOwnProperty(tags_entries[i])) {
            tags_entries.splice(i, 1);

        // Otherwise, score and add to results 
        } else {
            if (usr_tags.hasOwnProperty(tags_entries[i]['tag_id']))
            {   
                test.push(tags_entries[i]['tag_id']);

                if (result.hasOwnProperty(tags_entries[i][target]))
                {
                    result[tags_entries[i][target]]['score']++;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[tags_entries[i][target]]['score'] = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tags_entries.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    console.debug(test);

    // convert results to the desired object format
    return Object.keys(result).map(function (p){return {id: p, count: result[p]};});
}
```

**Problems:**

1. Most peculiar is that `console.debug(test)` will produce numbers that I haven't supplied in the `usr_tags` array.
2. `result[tags_entries[i][target]]['score']` results as NaN every time.
3. Even though I'm using `result[tags_entries[i][target]]['tags'].push(tags_entries[i]['tag_id']);` to create a list of related tags for every entry, I'm only getting one result in each 'tags' array.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!!**

Ideally, my result object would look something like this:

```
result = {
         4:
         { 
          'score': 2,
          'tags': [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 109, 110]
         }
         //,{etc...}
         }
```

Comment: `tags_entries` is an invalid object.. Objects in JS are key/val pairs `{ {key:val},{key:val}}` is invalid.

Comment: As @tymeJV, `tag_entries` should be defined as `tag_entries = [ ... ];` instead, if you want it to be an ordered list.

Comment: my mistake. tags_entries actually is an array and I've edited the question to account for it.

Comment: May i know what is the value you pass as target? score_relevance2(tags_entries, usr_tags, **target**)

Comment: target = 'entry_id';